# 31/5000 mouse position is not right in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

I have start to build a bot and i have try to get the mouse position store on a variable x and y and then wen i click start move the mouse to the location but wen i start the bot the location its not right.
How can i get the true position of it.
I have try like this but i cant get the correct position of mouse x,y inside of a webbrowser

I have made a gif image of the problem imgur link https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgw1o.jpg
I have also edit my code and try a different way but i can not get the correct position

This is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim horas
Dim minutos
Dim segundos
Dim milesimos
Dim ratobutao
Dim tipoclick
Dim repetir
Dim currentelocal
Dim xmouse
Dim ymouse
Dim WithEvents htmldoc As HtmlDocument
Private Sub htmldoc_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles htmldoc.MouseMove
    'TextBox5.Text = e.MousePosition.X.ToString
    'TextBox6.Text = e.MousePosition.Y.ToString
    'xmouse = e.MousePosition.X.ToString
    'ymouse = e.MousePosition.Y.ToString
End Sub
Private Sub htmldoc_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles htmldoc.MouseDown
    'xmouse = e.MousePosition.X.ToString
    'ymouse = e.MousePosition.Y.ToString
    'TextBox5.Text = e.MousePosition.X.ToString
    'TextBox6.Text = e.MousePosition.Y.ToString
    xmouse = Me.Width / WebBrowser1.Width
    ymouse = Me.Height / WebBrowser1.Height
    TextBox5.Text = e.MousePosition.X.ToString
    TextBox6.Text = e.MousePosition.Y.ToString
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    For Each c As Control In Controls
        AddHandler c.MouseClick, AddressOf ClickHandler
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub ClickHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick


    Select Case e.Button
        Case MouseButtons.Left
            MsgBox("left mouse")
            TextBox5.Text = xmouse
            TextBox6.Text = ymouse
            Label2.Text = "Left"
        Case MouseButtons.Right
            Label2.Text = "Right"
        Case MouseButtons.Middle
            Label2.Text = "Middle"
        Case Else
            Label2.Text = "Some other button"
    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    htmldoc = WebBrowser1.Document
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox5.Text = xmouse
    TextBox6.Text = ymouse

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(xmouse, ymouse)
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Define `true position`. Position of the web page? Web browser? Monitor? Windows?

Comment: @TyCobb tank you for replay i need the true position of the mouse x,y in side of a webbrowser , because wen i click the start button its go out of my chose place , its not accurate

Comment: How are you setting the mouse position? You need to compensate for the location of the window and the browser control. If you're using a global mouse move then the coordinates are relative to monitors.

Comment: @TyCobb yes wen i click start the mouse go to the location i have set before can you pls give me an example how to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When programming with graphical interfaces, there are three different coordinate sets you need to be aware of: Screen, Window, and Client. Different contexts provide coordinates from different areas. You need to know what type of coordinates you have, and how to convert between the others. This image illustrates:

[image: Different Coordinate Types]

In multi-monitor situations there may even be a fourth, to differentiate between a specific monitor and the entire desktop. Different windowing systems may also argue about what section counts as the client area, but the main thing is it's not the same as the others.

Figure out what coordinates you have in each situation in your code, and then look up how to convert between them.

Comment: Isn't the client everything minus the title bar and the client in the picture really the control? I guess it depends obviously on what's being used as the point of reference. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: I have try to do it like this but its not good                                      
     xmouse = Me.Width / WebBrowser1.Width
    ymouse = Me.Height / WebBrowser1.Height

Comment: @TyCobb  Generally, yes. I went back and forth on how to draw it for this situation. The client area is relative to a specific Window. In Windows, everything can be a window. Individual controls have their CreateWindow() call at the low-level of the Win32 API, and so anything can have a private client area.  I thought for this question it was more helpful to indicate the client area as the inside part of the web browser control. I especially wanted to exaggerate that it doesn't start at the top left.

Comment: @TyCobb is there any example of code to me to watch and stud how to do it Pls

Comment: @TyCobb i have try to change my code and its all much correct but not yet perfect i am sure i miss something i have try like this xmouse = WebBrowser1.Width
        ymouse = WebBrowser1.Height

Answer (score 0):

In fact after to try many different ways to get it .
I have solve the mystery :)
It is easy but there not that many information out there about, and well English its not my native Language and the way i try to search maybe not that efficient.
But i get it work perfect.
This is the working code

```
Private Sub htmldoc_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs) Handles htmldoc.MouseDown

    xmouse = Control.MousePosition.X.ToString()
    ymouse = Control.MousePosition.Y.ToString()

    TextBox5.Text = xmouse
    TextBox6.Text = ymouse
End Sub
```